# How can I say I learned from a well managed team?

Tags: software-industry, resume, career-development, developer

My team at my current company is very well managed, with proper use of Agile, Git, Grunt, code review culture. I want to say that it is a good team where I learned these skills at, without bragging, or making my other positions look bad. I was thinking something like:

> Worked on a well managed team implementing the latest development practices including continuously improvement scrum, GIT and code review culture, and GRUNT for builds.

Is it okay to make such claims (i.e. that the team was well managed)? Or rather, is it necessary?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about resume help which is off-topic.

Comment: Explaining that a team is managed well is subjective to opinion and cannot be easily proved.  I personally would concentrate on listing the technologies and methodologies you used rather than concentrating on less important finer details.

Comment: @JimG. this is my first workplace question - when I look at the resume tag, it seems there are a lot of other questions about them, so I assumed that this was acceptable. Sorry if this is out of bounds...

Comment: Hi woody. No apology is necessary. I was just trying to uphold the current rules. Feel free to ask your question in chat. Many users would likely be willing to offer their opinions.

Comment: I agree Joe - I suppose I say its proper agile since of the three companies i have worked for previously, they all claimed agile but really didn't have proper scrum, little to no involvement with design or product owners, and no continious self improvement. At the current place, all of these things are emphasized, and you can tell by the quality of product that comes out. Don't mean to hype the company, just that the pronounced difference is what prompted me to call it out. Thanks all!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Well managed" matters little, since the standards of each developer are different. Your well managed team can look like one that's clueless and in its infancy to a developer coming from a different environment. Emphasize the exact things you did instead.

> I have worked in an environment that focused on the latest agile
>   development practices, including scrum, code review culture, Git
>   version control and GRUNT for builds.

Comment: Thanks Alex! Do you think its worth it to spell out "Git version control" vs just assuming that people know what "Git" is?

Comment: Good question. I think it doesn't hurt to say something like "version control using Git", tbh. You avoid the case when the reader is not familiar with Git, as unlikely as that may seem, and you get the message over explicitly: "I am familiar with the workflow involved in version control, and I've used Git in practice", but in a shorter form.